# ListBox selection state Customization

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to change the background of a selected item in a listbox to some color, so i am changing the selection state in a style template:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Duration="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="YellowGreen"/>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <StackPanel x:Name="border" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, when i add this template to the listbox, it loads empty which is incorrect.
Also, i am binding the items in the listbox to the following itemtemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FlightsTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3" Background="#FF171717" Height="35">
    <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="60"  Text="{Binding Time}"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="80"  Text="{Binding Flight}"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="150" Text="{Binding City}"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="90"  Text="{Binding Status}"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="70"  Text="{Binding Expected_Time}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change ListBoxItem Template.
See the details here: http://forums.silverlight.net/post/64044.aspx

Comment: Sorry but this link wasn't helpful.  
I have the following example to customize the listbox:  
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-customize-the-WP7-ListBox-Selected-Item--Part2-Visual-States  


However as i said in the question above, when i bind the listbox to this style it doesn't show any entry in it anymore.