# Remove item from listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I am trying to remove an item from a listbox using C# code using the following line of code:

```
search_history.Items.RemoveAt(selected);
```

However I get the following message: **Operation not supported on read-only collection.**

What is the workaround solution for this problem other than resetting the listbox and entering the items all over again?

Comment: A little more information regarding search_history object and how selected are set please.

Comment: the search_history is simply the listbox name and selected is an integer with the selected item index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind your ListBox to a [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), by setting the `serach_history.ItemsSource = myObservableCollection`

Then you can do `myObservableCollection.Remove(search_history.SelectedItem)` and the item will be removed from the collection, and the UI will update accordingly.

In general, you should always aim to use [Data Bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amit_chatterjee/archive/2011/04/16/building-a-windows-phone-7-application-data-binding-and-persistence.aspx) rather than add items directly to a collection.

Comment: you are right about the binding thing and thanks for mentioning it, but the problem is that i need to customize the listbox and i can't understand the method to do so especially with selection state. Thus, i'm using the element addition thing through C# code.

Comment: Styles and DataTemplates aren't that difficult :) Take the time to try, and ask on Stack Overflow if you get in trouble.

Comment: This is the link of a question i posted a while ago about listbox selection state customization but never got answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979915/listbox-selection-state-customization

Answer (score 0):

```
search_history.Items.Remove(search_history.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: even this one gives the same exception :(

Answer (score 0):

Item of the itemsource should implement the INotifyCollectionChanged interface. To simplify matters, you can use the ObservableCollection< T > instead of the List< T >.
Then using the code shown below will work well:

```
(yourlistbox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<T>).RemoveAt(selected);
```

Hope that helps.